# Matlab: Dendrogram axes background color

Tags: matlab, colors, dendrogram

I've been looking through the Internet in vain trying to find out how to change the axes background color of a Matlab dendrogram. Since the normal way of simply writing,

```
set(ax5,'color',[0.9,0.9,0.98]);
```

does not seem to work, I tried to link the axes by first plotting the axes with the background color and then superimposing the dendrogram. But the dendrogram seems to have a non-transparent background and thus I wrote,

```
set(ax4,'color','none');
```

but that does not seem to work either. Is there any way to gain access to this parameter?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work on **MATLAB version R2019b**. This first thing I did was retrieve the current axes, `gca` to indicate which axes' background colour to change.

[image: Dendrogram Plot]

```
rng('default') % For reproducibility
X = rand(10,3);
tree = linkage(X,'average');
dendrogram(tree);

%Grabbing the current axis from most recent figure/plot%
Axes_1 = gca;
set(Axes_1,'color',[0.9,0.9,0.98]);
```

**Ran on MATLAB R2019b**